# Can't download base plugins in SBT

Tags: sbt

I'm trying to update my SBT by running `sbt update` and I keep getting an error that repo.scala-sbt.org is not available for basic packages such as sbt-native-packager. Is there something else I can do to use a different mirror of sbt?

Stack trace:

```
[error] lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.error.FetchError$DownloadingArtifacts: Error fetching artifacts:
[error] https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.5.2/jars/sbt-native-packager.jar: download
 error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException (Remote host terminated the handshake) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/
com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.5.2/jars/sbt-native-packager.jar
[error] https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-js-engine/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.2.3/docs/sbt-js-engine-javadoc.jar: download err
or: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException (Remote host terminated the handshake) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.
typesafe.sbt/sbt-js-engine/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.2.3/docs/sbt-js-engine-javadoc.jar
[error] https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.5.2/docs/sbt-native-packager-javadoc.jar:
download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException (Remote host terminated the handshake) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-r
eleases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.5.2/docs/sbt-native-packager-javadoc.jar
[error] https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-web/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.4.4/docs/sbt-web-javadoc.jar: download error: Caught j
avax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException (Remote host terminated the handshake) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt
/sbt-web/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.4.4/docs/sbt-web-javadoc.jar
[error]
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.Artifacts$.$anonfun$fetchArtifacts$9(Artifacts.scala:365)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.util.Task$.$anonfun$flatMap$extension$1(Task.scala:14)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.util.Task$.$anonfun$flatMap$extension$1$adapted(Task.scala:14)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.util.Task$.wrap(Task.scala:82)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.util.Task$.$anonfun$flatMap$2(Task.scala:14)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$flatMap$1(Future.scala:307)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:41)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[error] Caused by: lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.ArtifactError$DownloadError: download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException (Remote host te
rminated the handshake) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.5.2/jars
/sbt-native-packager.jar
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.internal.Downloader$.helper$2(Downloader.scala:748)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.internal.Downloader$.coursier$cache$internal$Downloader$$downloading(Downloader.scala:761)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.internal.Downloader$Blocking$.$anonfun$remote$1(Downloader.scala:406)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.CacheLocks$.loop$1(CacheLocks.scala:71)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.CacheLocks$.withLockOr(CacheLocks.scala:95)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.internal.Downloader$Blocking$.remote(Downloader.scala:408)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.internal.Downloader.$anonfun$remote$5(Downloader.scala:510)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
[error]         at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
[error]         at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[error] Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
[error]         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1701)
[error]         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1519)
[error]         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421)
[error]         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:456)
[error]         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
[error]         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:580)
[error]         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:201)
[error]         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1592)
[error]         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
[error]         at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)
[error]         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:334)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.CacheUrl$.redirectTo(CacheUrl.scala:176)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.CacheUrl$.redirect(CacheUrl.scala:191)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.CacheUrl$.urlConnectionMaybePartial(CacheUrl.scala:347)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.ConnectionBuilder.connectionMaybePartial(ConnectionBuilder.scala:50)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.internal.Downloader$Blocking$.doDownload(Downloader.scala:220)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.internal.Downloader$Blocking$.$anonfun$remote$2(Downloader.scala:406)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.internal.Downloader$.$anonfun$downloading$1(Downloader.scala:715)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.CacheLocks$.withUrlLock(CacheLocks.scala:114)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.internal.Downloader$.helper$2(Downloader.scala:715)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.internal.Downloader$.coursier$cache$internal$Downloader$$downloading(Downloader.scala:761)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.internal.Downloader$Blocking$.$anonfun$remote$1(Downloader.scala:406)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.CacheLocks$.loop$1(CacheLocks.scala:71)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.CacheLocks$.withLockOr(CacheLocks.scala:95)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.internal.Downloader$Blocking$.remote(Downloader.scala:408)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.internal.Downloader.$anonfun$remote$5(Downloader.scala:510)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
[error]         at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
[error]         at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[error] Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
[error]         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:489)
[error]         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
[error]         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:160)
[error]         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
[error]         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1511)
[error]         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421)
[error]         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:456)
[error]         at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
[error]         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:580)
[error]         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:201)
[error]         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1592)
[error]         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
[error]         at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)
[error]         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:334)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.CacheUrl$.redirectTo(CacheUrl.scala:176)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.CacheUrl$.redirect(CacheUrl.scala:191)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.CacheUrl$.urlConnectionMaybePartial(CacheUrl.scala:347)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.ConnectionBuilder.connectionMaybePartial(ConnectionBuilder.scala:50)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.internal.Downloader$Blocking$.doDownload(Downloader.scala:220)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.internal.Downloader$Blocking$.$anonfun$remote$2(Downloader.scala:406)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.internal.Downloader$.$anonfun$downloading$1(Downloader.scala:715)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.CacheLocks$.withUrlLock(CacheLocks.scala:114)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.internal.Downloader$.helper$2(Downloader.scala:715)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.internal.Downloader$.coursier$cache$internal$Downloader$$downloading(Downloader.scala:761)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.internal.Downloader$Blocking$.$anonfun$remote$1(Downloader.scala:406)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.CacheLocks$.loop$1(CacheLocks.scala:71)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.CacheLocks$.withLockOr(CacheLocks.scala:95)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.internal.Downloader$Blocking$.remote(Downloader.scala:408)
[error]         at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.internal.Downloader.$anonfun$remote$5(Downloader.scala:510)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
[error]         at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
[error]         at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
[error]         at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[error] (update) lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.error.FetchError$DownloadingArtifacts: Error fetching artifacts:
[error] https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.5.2/jars/sbt-native-packager.jar: download
 error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException (Remote host terminated the handshake) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/
com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.5.2/jars/sbt-native-packager.jar
[error] https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-js-engine/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.2.3/docs/sbt-js-engine-javadoc.jar: download err
or: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException (Remote host terminated the handshake) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.
typesafe.sbt/sbt-js-engine/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.2.3/docs/sbt-js-engine-javadoc.jar
[error] https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.5.2/docs/sbt-native-packager-javadoc.jar:
download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException (Remote host terminated the handshake) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-r
eleases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.5.2/docs/sbt-native-packager-javadoc.jar
[error] https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-web/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.4.4/docs/sbt-web-javadoc.jar: download error: Caught j
avax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException (Remote host terminated the handshake) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt
/sbt-web/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.4.4/docs/sbt-web-javadoc.jar
```

I tried looking into the repo manually, and it seems to redirect back to jfrog website which hosts the jars on AWS but it's currently not available for some reason

Comment: Only for sbt native packager? Have you tried to use different versions of that plugin? The problem is only for plugins? Dependencies also? Have you tried to run a new project from scratch? Have you tried to run the project with issues in another computer? In a server? Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @GastónSchabas, i tried doing it with several versions from different computers, the problem is that the endpoint is not available for the sbt-native-packager plugin (as well as a few other plugins) through the repo.scala-sbt.org host:

Comment: maybe [unavailable repo.scala-sbt.org (April 7, 2023)](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/7202) and [play-samples-play-scala-hello-world-tutorial - Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/11596) can help you